# Changing the width of AutoCompleteTextView in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-listview, autocompletetextview

I've been stumped on this for a few days. I have an autoCompleteTextView and a button split 50/50 in my layout. The autocomplete works, but the suggestions only take up half of the screen (equivalent to the size that my textView takes up). How could I change this to take up the whole width?

Pardon my terrible paint skills:

Blue = AutoCompleteTextView
Red = desired autocomplete suggestions

This seems like a trivial problem, but simply changing the width to fill_parent doesn't work. Any ideas xml or programatically?

### **SOLUTION:** myAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)

[image]

**EDIT:**
My first question seems to be solved, but now if I switch my button and my autoCompleteTextView I get another weird problem. The width starts at where the textView starts. Leaving me with an undesireable result.

### **SOLUTION:** See edit 1 from user: vikram

[image]

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can set this attribute in the description of this widget using the attribute:

```
android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
```

If you would like to do this in java 'programmatically', use the method `setDropDownWidth(int)`:

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(int)
```

**Edit 1:**

```
Point pointSize = new Point();

getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(pointSize);

myAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(pointSize.x);
```

Comment: How would I pass in the width of the root layout?

Comment: Well, you can calculate the screen width and pass that into `setDropDownWidth(screenWidth)`. Or, you can pass in the `MATCH_PARENT` constant as `setDropDownWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)`. Or, you can have `setDropDownWidth(-1)`, `-1` being the value of `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`. Was this what you were asking?

Comment: Hmm... yeah that seems to work, but now I have another problem. I'm updating my question.

Comment: What are you using as the argument in setDropDownWidth(?)?

Comment: `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`

Comment: Ok. We'll get the screen width and set it explicitly. See Edit 1 above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33933/discussion-between-eghdk-and-vikram)

Comment: Great dude:) have been slogging for this answer:)

Comment: Is there a way to center the dropDown PopUp and keep it with a width larger than the autocompletetextview itself but not with a MATCH_PARENT width?

Comment: @user3019105 Perhaps. You can try that by replacing `myAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth(pointSize.x);` with `myAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownWidth((pointSize.x + myAutoCompleteTextView.getWidth()) / 2);`. I am not sure if this will center the drop-down horizontally, but its worth a try.

Answer (score 10):

I find `setDropDownAnchor()` to be much more convenient.

Just pass the id of some view and drop down view will match its width and position (no matter where the actual text view is placed).

In your example that could be the parent of both: button and text view.

Answer (score 2):

In my case `AutoCompleteTextView` occupied a whole width. Looking at [change position of spinner dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610810/change-position-of-spinner-dropdown-list/30867614) I set

```
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
```

to create left and right margins of a list.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also adjust where the width start with:

```
myAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownHorizontalOffset(int offset)
```