# change position of spinner dropdown list

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I need to change the horisontal position of Spinner's dropdown list. 
here's the screenshot :

[image]

and I want this dropdown list to go in one line under the main icon/text so it would look fine

As on the picture :

[image]

here's what I do in xml :

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/tvHeader"
    style="@style/spinner_style"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ver_main_donate_background_tile_long"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ver_main_donate_background_tile_long"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_main_header"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="-15dp"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"

    android:text="@string/name_of_product" />
```

so, as I suppose,

```
android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="-15dp"
```

should do the trick, but as you see on the screenshot it doesn't work

Comment: Don't use wrap_content on your width.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: i dont seem to get it what do you want to change actually @AnubianNoob

Comment: The drop down is not aligned with the spinner in the first picture. I'm having the same problem. Setting the horizontal offset to negative does not seem to solve the problem, the drop down can't move further left.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

You can observe that the list items are aligned slight right, from the parent
So i added a marginLeft attribute in spinner view

```
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
```

and thats worked for me, below you can see the difference

[image]

Comment: What if I don't want to move the spinner? Is there a way to have the dropdown aligned with the side of the window?

Comment: i think , there is no other way

Comment: I was sorta hoping for an explanation of that. Any idea why it's impossible?

Comment: @AnubianNoob Even if he is right that there is no way to customize the dropdown location, asside from this, you could easily move the position of the spinner back to where it was by adjusting it's layout within the parent container (ex, adding a -20dp margin left).

Comment: Alternatively you could do a custom popup window, with a custom list view, so anything is possible.  But that's a large hassle, and it doesn't automatically do things like close the spinner

Answer (score 1):

Use this to make the button as you want

```
    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
    getActionBar().setIcon(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));   
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar);
```

And this is the costume layout

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|right"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="-6dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:text="wheresmyTURF"
    android:textColor="#ffff"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    app:customTypeface="fonts/pompiere.ttf" />
```

by this you customize the action bar so you can make some changes as you need i think....

Answer (score 1):

You could just make the Spinner without the triangle.

First, create a styles.xml file under res/values, open it and add the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style parent="@android:style/Widget.Spinner" 
name="SpinnerAsEditText"><item 
name="android:background">@android:drawable/edit_text</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Next, in your layout, add the Spinner like this:

```
<Spinner style="@style/SpinnerAsEditText" anyOtherAttributeYouNeed="..."></Spinner>
```

When you use it like this you Spinner will look just like a EditText without the little triangle.